# jQM mobile listview subsearch

Tags: jquery, html, listview, mobile, cordova

I am making a jQM and PhoneGap application, and I have one main page with listview and search:

```
<div data-role="page" id="penalties">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>driver.io</h1>
</header>
<article data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Pretraga">
<li>
<a href="#alkohol" data-transition="none">
<h1>Alkohol</h1>
<img src="icons/alcohol.png" alt="Alkohol" />
<p><span class="ui-li-count">6</span></p>
<p class="ui-li-desc">Ne pijem kad vozim</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#psihoaktiv" data-transition="none">
<h1>Psihoaktivne supstance</h1>
<img src="icons/drugs.png" alt="Psihoaktivne supstance" />
<p><span class="ui-li-count">2</span></p>
<p class="ui-li-desc">Droga(ne)</p>
</a>
</li>
```

and so on as far as the li's go.

Now, clicking on each of these list items opens up a new page with another listview:

```
<div data-role="page" id="alkohol">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>Kazne za alkohol</h1>
<a href="#penalties" data-transition="none" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="home"  data-iconpos="notext" data-sort="true">Prekršaji</a>
</header>
<article data-role="content" >
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Prekršaji vezani za alkohol" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#alc_one" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="none">Prevoz lica koje je pod uticajem alkohola na mopedu, motociklu, triciklu</a></li>
<li><a href="#alc_two" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="none">Vožnja sa 0,31 do 0,5 promila alkohola u krvi - umerena alkoholisanost</a></li>
```

I am looking for a way to search all of these list items on subpages through the data-filter on the first page, and showing them to the user.

I did a lot of search, but didn't end up with a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not looking to cache my data, it's already present in the DOM, I just need to find a way to present relevant data in another listview when a user does a search.

Comment: You can use localStorage.setItem("listview", listviewdata) and localStorage.getItem(listview); for local storage when user search.

Comment: Thanks Ved, sorted this out quite a while ago and tried your suggestion which worked, just wanted to say thank you!